# New to C#, not all code paths return a value, Bottle counting program, switch statement

Tags: c#, debugging, switch-statement

Hello I've reached a stump that I cannot pull out.

My program records the number of bottles collected by four rooms. The program should prompt me to enter a room number and then how many bottles that room has collected. When ever the user types in "quit" the program will spit out the bottles collected by each room and calculate the room with the most bottles collected. I should be able to add bottles to each room as long as I haven't typed in quit.

I cannot get my GetRoom (int room) working, that is the method that does not return a value.
How would I find the room with the most bottles collected? Math.Max?

I cannot use LINQ or arrays. Its part of the assignment rules. 
Heres is my code:

```
namespace BottleDrive1
{
    class Program
    {//Initialize 4 rooms. 
        int room1 = 0;

        int room2 = 0;

        int room3 = 0;

        int room4 = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Start of while loop to ask what room your adding into. 
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: ");
                //If user enters quit at anytime, the code will jump out of while statement and enter for loop below
                string quit = Console.ReadLine();
                if (quit == "quit")
                    //Break statement allows quit to jump out of loop
                    break;
            }
        }

        private void SetRoom(int room, int value)
        {
            switch (room)
            {
                case 1:
                    room1 = value;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    room2 = value;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    room3 = value;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    room4 = value;
                    break;
            }
        }
        public void GetRoom(int room)
        {
            int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (room)
            {
                case 1:
                    room1 += count;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    room2 += count;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    room3 += count;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    room4 += count;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new ArgumentException();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The braces are not formatted well.

Comment: you have an extra brace after the break statement in your loop

Comment: Visual studio says it expects 2 brackets there< i have updated my code to the most recent

Comment: Where and how are you trying to use the GetRoom function and what specifically are you wanting to return? I just see the declaration in your code.

Comment: @Mark Hall My first switch is to determine what room I am storing the data. The second switch is to determine how many bottles each room as collected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example that uses a Class to hold the information for each room. The reason for using a class is so that if your program needs to change in the future to collect more information, you won't have to track yet another array, you can just add properties to the class.

The individual rooms are now held in a list instead of an array just to show a different construct.

Here is the new Room class:

```
public class Room
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int BottleCount { get; set; }

    public Room(int wNumber)
    {
        Number = wNumber;
    }
}
```

And here is the new version of the program. Note that additional checking of the values entered by the end user has been added in order to prevent exceptions when trying to get the current room or parse to an int the value entered by the user:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int MAX_ROOMS = 4;
        var cRooms = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Room>();

        for (int nI = 0; nI < MAX_ROOMS; nI++)
        {
            // The room number is 1 to 4
            cRooms.Add(new Room(nI + 1));
        }

        // Initializes the room that wins
        //Start of while loop to ask what room your adding into. 
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: ");
            //If user enters quit at anytime, the code will jump out of while statement and enter for loop below
            string roomNumber = Console.ReadLine();
            if (roomNumber == "quit")
            {
                //Break statement allows quit to jump out of loop
                break;
            }
            int room = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(roomNumber, out room) && (room < MAX_ROOMS) && (room >= 0)) {
                Room currentRoom;

                currentRoom = cRooms[room];

                Console.Write("Bottles collected in room {0}: ", currentRoom.Number);

                int wBottleCount = 0;

                if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out wBottleCount) && (wBottleCount >= 0))
                {
                    // This line adds the count of bottles and records it so you can continuously count the bottles collected.
                    currentRoom.BottleCount += wBottleCount;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid bottle count; value must be greater than 0");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid room number; value must be between 1 and " + MAX_ROOMS.ToString());
            }
        }

        Room maxRoom = null;

        foreach (Room currentRoom in cRooms) //This loop goes through the array of rooms (4)
        {
            // This assumes that the bottle count can never be decreased in a room
            if ((maxRoom == null) || (maxRoom.BottleCount < currentRoom.BottleCount))
            {
                maxRoom = currentRoom;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Bottles collected in room {0} = {1}", currentRoom.Number, currentRoom.BottleCount);
        }
        //Outputs winner
        Console.WriteLine("And the Winner is room " + maxRoom.Number + "!!!");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your function returns something. Have you tried compiling this code? It has a compile error that would fix your method.

And Math.Max is a good way to find the max.

Comment: The compile error "Error 1 'BottleDrive1.Program.GetRoom(int)': not all code paths return a value"

Comment: You need to return the room that is being requested before you call break;

Comment: Like this? case 1:
room1 += count;
 return room1;
but if i put break after my return, i will not be able to access the break with the return there.

Comment: the break is not needed since you have the return statement.

Comment: Is a return statement better than break? ie. return room1;

Answer (score 1):

The `GetRoom` method does not return a value. Either provide a default value in a switch statement or and a return statement after that. Also, you can raise an exception in these cases.

Example:

```
public int GetRoom(int room)
{
    int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    switch (room)
    {
        case 1:
            room1 += count;
            break;
        case 2:
            room2 += count;
            break;
        case 3:
            room3 += count;
            break;
        case 4:
            room4 += count;
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException(); //either this
    }
    throw new ArgumentException(); //or this
}
```

BTW, you can use an array of 4 elements instead of 4 different variables, that will simplify your existing code and save you some time writing new. For example, `GetRoom` will look like this:

```
public int GetRoom(int room)
{
    int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    rooms[room] += count;
    //return what you need to return here
}
```

Comment: public int GetRoom(int room)
{
int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
switch (room)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            room1 += count;
                            return room1;
                        case 2:
                            room2 += count;
                            return room2;
                        case 3:
                            room3 += count;
                            return room3;
                        case 4:
                            room4 += count;
                            return room4;
}

Comment: +1 for the array suggestion. @George: for several reasons, please consider abandoning the `switch` statement and use an array (or a list) of rooms. You won't be limited to four rooms and your code will be much more concise and easier to follow.

Comment: I am not allowed to use arrays in this piece of code. The objective is to show arrays are much prominent, I did my first revision using array, worked perfect, but now converting that array to switch is hard.

Comment: Oh, I've missed that part of the question, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `GetRoom` method is defined to return an `int` and hence it must do so on every code path.  This particular example doesn't return a value on any path.

Based on the logic within the `GetRoom` method though it seems like you're modifying rooms instead of returning one.  If that's the case simply switch the method to return `void`

```
public void GetRoom() {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the void make it so my program passes debugging. But now i cant get through the "Console.Write("Enter the room you're in: ");" loop. It keeps asking me for the room number no matter what i enter.

Comment: @GeorgeLi you need to call the GetRoom or SetRoom based on the input. It's hard to tell from the sample what you want the flow to be based on the input values

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from your function at all. Try something like this, store your result in a temporary variable then when you exit the function return it.

```
public int GetRoom(int room)
{
    int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int temp = 0;
    switch (room)
    {
        case 1:
            room1 += count;
            temp = room1;
            break;
        case 2:
            room2 += count;
            temp = room2;
            break;
        case 3:
            room3 += count;
            temp = room3;
            break;
        case 4:
            room4 += count;
            temp = room4;
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    return temp;

}
```

Comment: @GeorgeLi - No problem you're welcome. You may want to look over your old questions that you have asked and [accept the answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that where helpful to you